# sample angularjs code which will connects to sqllite

Tags: angularjs, sqlite

kindly provide a  sample code/link/tutorial which will connect to sqllite database from anugular js.
I am new mobile development

Basically when i am calling retriveProfileInfo function which is present in DataAccess.js

retriveProfileInfo function is executing in different thread i wanted in synchronous way.
Controller.js

```
mympn.controller('MyProfileController', function($scope, $location, ngDialog ) {

    $scope.myProfileData = {};
    $scope.myProfileDatalist = [];
    function callBack(d) {
        return d;
    }
    $scope.myProfileDatalist = retriveProfileInfo(callBack);

    alert(myProfileDatalist);
    console
            .log("After calling retriveProfileInfo ----------------");



});
```

DataAccess.js

```
function retriveProfileInfo(callBack) {
    var db = DataBaseInstance.getInstance();
    var userProfileData = [];
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql("SELECT * from myprofile", [], function(tx, res) {
             for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
                 userProfileData[i] = res.rows.item(i);
              }
        });
    }, errorCB, sucessCB);
    console.log(userProfileData);
    return callBack(userProfileData);
}
```

Comment: You are better searching on Google if you are simply looking for sample code for this. This site is best suited to help with issues you are stuck with, for example, providing methods you have tried so far or code you are stuck with and people will be better able to offer advice.

Comment: updated with the problem.